# R not recognizing factors in regression

Tags: r

I am running linear probability models in R and have defined certain variables as factors, e.g.:

```
r_js<-factor(birth$r_js)

r_pp<-factor(birth$r_pp)

r_cp<-factor(birth$r_cp)

r_cs<-factor(birth$r_cs)
```

However, when I run my models, R doesn't recognize these as factors. Here's the output:

```
Call:
   felm(formula = pc ~ r_cn + r_js + r_pp + r_cp + r_cs | cnty +      year, data = birth) 

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.2700 -0.1505 -0.1347 -0.1156  0.9362 

Coefficients:
       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
r_cn  0.0020020  0.0017050   1.174 0.240312    
r_js -0.0022204  0.0021751  -1.021 0.307345    
r_pp  0.0027668  0.0009196   3.009 0.002622 ** 
r_cp  0.0023981  0.0011860   2.022 0.043164 *  
r_cs  0.0058436  0.0016471   3.548 0.000389 ***
```

If I do a series of class() calls on these variables, R confirms that they are of class "factor".

Now, if I try to replicate the results with a toy dataset, I'm unable. Here's the toy dataset with variables defined:

```
demo <- data.frame(expand.grid(country = c("USA","USA","China","China","Sudan","Sudan"),
                               year = 1994:1996),
                   democratic = round(runif(9, 0, 20), 0),
                   UN = rbinom(18,1,0.5))

pzb<-factor(demo$UN)
pzdemo<-demo$democratic
pzyear<-demo$year
```

And here's the output of a regression:

```
Call:
lm(formula = pzdemo ~ pzb + pzyear)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-12.091  -1.971   0.169   3.849   5.829 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 1926.7582  3086.6617   0.624    0.542
pzb1           0.7606     2.5916   0.293    0.773
pzyear        -0.9601     1.5473  -0.620    0.544
```

R treats "pzb" as a factor, as denoted by the "1" after "pzb". A similarity between the toy dataset and mine: if I simply define the variables in both datasets without the factor() function, then the variables are of class "integer." Now, here's the difference (and maybe that's what causes the anomaly): when I define variables in my dataset, they are "large factors".

A few other things to note: if I do the following:

```
birth$r_js<-factor(birth$r_js)
r_js<-birth$r_js
```

Then R correctly treats `r_js` as a factor. Similarly, if I don't do the above, but in the regression formula I use `factor(r_js)` then R treats that variable as a factor.

I would appreciate any explanation for what's going on and why a simple `r_js<-factor(birth$r_js)` doesn't work here.

Comment: `r_js<-factor(birth$r_js)` is the problem - `r_js` is not the same as `birth$r_js`. You have to overwrite the variable in your data.frame. `birth$r_js <- factor(birth$r_js)`

Comment: But why is that not true for `pzb<-factor(demo$UN)` in the above example? R treats `pzb` as a factor even though if I did `pzb<-demo$UN` then `pzb` would be treated as numeric.

Comment: Because in your first `lm()` you have `data = birth`, which means the formula will reference variables/columns inside `birth` first, rather than the standalone variable in your global workspace. Your `demo` works because you don't specify `data=demo` - which would have the same problem as your original example.

Comment: @thelatemail I removed `data=` and now it works! I specify the dataframe out of habit, but I suppose if I have all my variables defined, then I don't need to do that step.

Comment: You should use the `data=` though. It reduces ambiguity in your code. You should change your `factor`-creating code to overwrite the variables inside your `data.frame` and then keep the `data=` reference when calling `lm`. If you can avoid having free-floating variables in your workspace, that is a good thing.